# How can I optimize pathData in VectorDrawable

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have a very complex pathData in my VectorDrawable, it's about 200K symbols. Is there a way or a tool to optimize it? Because I'm getting `invalid pathData string too long` error. Any suggestions are very appreciated